# File writing not working in PHP/MAFFT when executed in a web page

Tags: php, bash, shell, bioinformatics

I am working on a web based project that executes a program on the server called MAFFT. MAFFT takes as arguments an input file and a file to write the output to.

```
    mafft in > out
```

I have a php page that calls this:

```
    <?php
        shell_exec("mafft in > out);
    ?>
```

I have also tried a shell script (scr.sh):

```
    #!/bin/bash
    mafft in > out
```

Then:

```
    <?php
        shell_exec("sh ./scr.sh");
    ?>
```

When I run either the shell script or the php file from the command line

```
    php something.php
```

it works exactly as it is supposed to, but when I just navigate to the page in a web browser, it creates the out file but does not write to it (even if I change the output file perm to 777).

The in/out files can be pretty large since this is sequence alignment stuff, but I am testing with less than 200 character files.

Is there something that I am missing here or is it just not possible to do this from a web page?

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: You should post the full path to `sh`: ie. `shell_exec("/bin/sh ./scr.sh");`. Most of these problems result from either permission issues or the `PATH` environment variable not being set properly.

Comment: @FlorinStingaciu I added your recommendation, it still creates the output file but does not write to it.

Comment: Try piping the stderr into the output using `2>&1 >`. Maybe you'll get a hint as to what's wrong.

Comment: Also it may be helpful to look through your `httpd` error logs typically located under `/var/logs/httpd/`.

Comment: When looking at the httpd error log I find /usr/bin/mafft: 1961: /usr/bin/mafft: cannot create /dev/stderr: Permission denied

Comment: [Relevant](http://dbaspot.com/linux-misc/250987-permission-denied-dev-stderr-dev-stdout.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help Florin!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that the program (MAFFT) outputs its progress as it runs, but executing it through a web page did not give it the permissions required to do so, so it exited without completing. Sending the programs output to /dev/null in the shell script seems to have solved it.